# importing data from a csv file using Batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to extract data from csv file and displaying it. But my output is not not as desired.
What is wrong in my code? My code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var1=0

for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (text.csv) do (
    set var2=0
    set var3=0
    set array[!var1!][!var2!]=%%a
    set /a var3=var2+1
    set array[!var1!][!var3!]=%%b
    set /a var3+=1
    set array[!var1!][!var3!]=%%c
    set /a var1+=1
)

echo First column, First element: %array[0][0]%
echo First column, Second element: %array[0][1]%
echo First column, Third element: %array[0][2]%
echo Second column, First element: %array[1][0]%
echo Second column, Second element: %array[1][1]%
echo Second column, Third element: %array[0][2]%

pause >nul
```

The content of `text.csv` file is displayed below:

```
DK joshi,152,uttarakhand,1  
amit,154,UP,2  
pooja,36,Haryana,3  
naveen,565, uttar pradesh,4  
suyal,985,uk,5
```

The displayed output by the code is given below:

```
First column, First element: DK joshi
First column, Second element: 152,uttarakhand,1
First column, Third element: %c
Second column, First element: amit
Second column, Second element: 154,UP,2
Second column, Third element: %c
```

Required output should be:

```
First column, First element: DK joshi
First column, Second element: 152
First column, Third element:uttarakhand
Second column, First element: amit
Second column, Second element: 154
Second column, Third element: UP
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use three separate tokens, you have to explicitly tell the loop that.

`"tokens=1* delims=," %%a` means "When you split the string, I want you to put the first part in `%%a` and everything else in `%%b`, and I want that thing that you split on to be `,`."

If you want to use `%%a`, `%%b`, and `%%c`, then you need to either list `tokens=1,2,3` or give the range `tokens=1-3`.